# Is bribery a sin according to Hindu scripture? If yes, what is the punishment?

Tags: mahabharata, scripture, ramayana, sin

Is bribery a sin according to [Hindu scripture](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/2995)?

If yes, what is the punishment? For example, the Indian Government's [Prevention of Corruption Act, 1988](http://www.persmin.gov.in/DOPT/EmployeesCorner/Acts_Rules/PCAct/pcact.pdf) has prescribed the following.

> CHAPTER III: OFFENCES AND PENALTIES
>
> **7. Public servant taking gratification other than legal remuneration in respect of an
>   official act**
>
> Whoever, being, or expecting to be a public servant, accepts or obtains or agrees to accept or
>   attempts to obtain from any person, for himself or for any other person, any gratification
>   whatever, other than legal remuneration, as a motive or reward for doing or forbearing to do
>   any official act or for showing or forbearing to show, in the exercise of his official functions,
>   favour or disfavour to any person or for rendering or attempting to render any service or
>   disservice to any person, with the Central Government or any State Government or
>   Parliament or the Legislature of any State or with any local authority, corporation or
>   Government company referred to in clause (c) of section 2, or with any public servant,
>   whether named or otherwise, **shall be punishable with imprisonment which shall be not less
>   than six months but which may extend to five years and shall also be liable to fine.**

Are there any examples from Ramayana and Mahabharata that touch upon this issue and how the kings in those epics dealt with this malady?

<sub>P.S: If you just want to state your opinion just leave a comment under the question. Please don't answer [citing blogs](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/94/2995) or Wikipedia. I'm mainly looking for answers backed by [scripture](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/2995). Answers can also be opinions of an āchārya or a guru.</sub>

Comment: In Virata-Parava, Pandavas seek advice from sage Dhaumya on how to live incognito as a household and not be discovered. Here's his stand on bribery _"Commissioned to a task, one should not touch bribes for by
such appropriation one becometh liable to fetters or death."_ This may be more inclined towards how to be a loyal household.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes bribery is considered as sin in Hinduism.

According to [Vishnu Purana, Book 2, Chapter 6](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp064.htm):

> He who takes unlawful gifts goes to the Adhomukha (or head-inverted) hell

According to [Mahabharata, Virata Parva](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m04/m04004.htm):

> Commissioned to a task, one should not touch bribes for by such appropriation one becometh liable to fetters or death.

According to [Manu Smriti, Chapter 9](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu09.htm), a King should always be alert with those who take bribe.

> 258. Those who take bribes, cheats and rogues, gamblers, those who live by teaching (the performance of) auspicious ceremonies, sanctimonious hypocrites, and fortune-tellers,

Padma Purana, Bhoomi Khanda, Chapter 67 also say the same thing as:

> That king whose subjects are harassed by officials receiving bribes, by thieves in his kingdom, is roasted in hells.

Also from this verse from [**Vaman Purana**](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/vamana-purana/chapter-12/topic-1)  (Chapter 12 verse 37) ,we come to know that accepting bribe is a sin & those who accept the bribe are thrown to hell.

> पृष्ठमांसाशिनो मूढास्तथैवोत्तकीव जीवन:। 
>   क्षिप्यन्ते वृकभक्षे ते
> नरके रजनीचर॥३७॥
>
> PrusthaManSaShiNo MudhaStaThaiVoTtaKiva Jivanah Kshpyate VrukBhakshe
> Te Narake RanajiChara
>
> **Meaning** - O monster ! The sneaking and bribe accepting rudes are
> thrown into the hell called "Vrakbhaksa".