# What do scriptures say about greed & corruption?

Tags: scripture, dharma, sin

These days if you see people are always greedy about others' money. The theives & beggars in the society are increasing. Some common examples include

1. One borrowss money from others and will not show intent to repay it.
2. Being thankless even after being helped.
3. Bus conductor takes money to give ticket but will not repay the change.
4. One friend always looks who gives party in college but he will never give to others :).
5. One growsup with the help of their parents but will not care about them in their old ages.
6. Even the education system became highly expensive.

There are many more examples apart from above. Corruption increased everywhere in society because of greed.

What did various scriptures say about greed and what will be the punishment to these people?

Comment: Gita doesn't talk about Dharma-ShAstra, hence such things will not have a direct answer. It's better to use "scripture" instead of "Gita".

Comment: Possible duplicates of [Is bribery a sin according to Hindu scripture? If yes, what is the punishment?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15090/3500) and [Dharma Shastras on Black Money, Corruption and paying Interest](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15784/3500)