# What is/are the punishment(s) for corruption?

Tags: dharma, punishment

Corruption is a dishonest or fraudulent conduct by those in power, typically involving bribery. More particularly, **Bribery** is a specific offence which concerns the practice of offering something, usually money, to gain an illicit advantage and **corruption** is an abuse of a position of trust in order to gain an undue advantage. For bribery, [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/is-bribery-a-sin-according-to-hindu-scripture-if-yes-what-is-the-punishment) is a similar question & answer. But I'm interested in Corruption.

- What are/is punishment(s) for doing corruption in this life?
- What are/is punishment(s) reserved for doing corruption in afterlife?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is bribery a sin according to Hindu scripture? If yes, what is the punishment?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/is-bribery-a-sin-according-to-hindu-scripture-if-yes-what-is-the-punishment)

Comment: @sv. He already mentions it in question. I think corruption is broad term.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Ok, didn't read the whole question. Yes, corruption is a broad term so this is a very broad question. One meaning of corruption is 'moral perversion' which can mean prostitution, pedophilia etc. Now I don't think OP meant all that.